# A javascript framework, both server-side and client-side, for describing forms and validating them?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, validation, mongoose, mean-stack

Is there a javascript framework, both server-side and client-side, for describing advanced forms and validating them?

In single page applications, front-end and back-end logics are dissociated. Ideally, form validation is first done at the front-end level -by the browser- in a user-friendly way. Then, form data is sent to the back-end and validated again -by the server- prior to insertion in the database or treatment.

Using the MEAN-stack, javascript is at work at both ends. Leveraging the same framework for validating user input data at front-end and back-end levels would greatly make the web app development faster and more robust.

By 'describing advanced form' I mean a description of the data where validation of a field can depend on the value of other fields as well as the visibility or the fact that a field is required is not necessarily constant and could depend on the values of other fields (ideally the validation could be described through a callback).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

Since you are using **Node.js** you can leverage form building by using [node-forms](https://github.com/caolan/forms) to dynamically build the front end forms, validate them and so on.